# How to return indices from sorting a 2d numpy array row-by-row?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

Input: A 2D numpy array

Output: An array of indices that will sort the array row by row (or column by column)

E.g.: Say the function is get_sorted_indices(array, axis=0)

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5]
             ,[2,3,4,5,6]
             ,[1,2,3,4,5]
             ,[2,3,4,6,6]
             ,[2,3,4,5,6]])

ind = get_sorted_indices(a, axis=0)
```

Then we will get

```
>>> ind 
[0, 2, 1, 4, 3]
>>> a[ind]   # should be equals to a.sort(axis = 0)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 3, 4, 6, 6]])
>>> a.sort(axis=0) 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 3, 4, 6, 6]])
```

I've looked at argsort but I don't understand its output and reading the documentation doesn't help:

```
>>> a.argsort() 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])

>>> a.argsort(axis=0) 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 3, 4]])
```

I can do this manually but I think I'm misunderstanding argsort or I'm missing something from numpy. 
Is there a standard way to do this or I have no choice but to do this manually?

Comment: Use `lexsort` : `np.lexsort(a.T)`.

Comment: Oh wow. That works! Thank you. I saw lexsort but couldn't really understand it from the documentation